# Maximum integer size

Tags: php, binary, integer, size, logical-operators

I can write into variable a big integer (which is > 2^32), and then print it

```
$bigInteger = 712940127394567;
echo $bigInteger;
```

But in formated view (boolean) I get just zero

```
printf("%b", $bigInteger);  // 0
```

Also, in logical operations, too big integers are meaning zero

```
$int = 1;
// getting 2^128, using cycle, because 2<<128 works just with <32
for($i=0; $i<128; $i++){
    $int *= 2;
}
$int -= 1;  // 111111.... x127
if (($int & (1 << 8)) == (1 << 8)) {
    echo 'Found that bit';  // 
}
```

Is it possible to use binary operators with extra big integers?

Comment: This isn't a __big integer__ in PHP, PHP doesn't have any integer datatype other than [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), which is limited to 32-bit or 64-bit signed; your value is being converted to a __float__ because the value is too large to store as an integer

Comment: @Mark I understand, that there is no big integer data type, and even if my number is converted to float - I assume, that any data type is, in fact, some amount of bits. The question is "can I use binary operators with that thing?"

Comment: You can, but you have to remember that your binary operations are being executed against an IETF float - http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wood-ldapext-float-00 - not against a signed integer